# JSON Data producing key error for nested data

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm getting a key error when trying to access some nested JSON data, this is because i am struggling to print the SECOND set of data under ["updates"] , see code below:

```
for url in URLs:
    JSONdata = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies, verify=False) .json()
    notifications = JSONdata["notifications"]
    for JSONkey in notifications:
        outDiscards = JSONkey["updates"]["outDiscards"]["value"]["avg"]["float"]
        inDiscards = JSONkey["updates"]["inDiscards"]["value"]["avg"]["float"]
        name = JSONkey["path_elements"][1]
        interface = JSONkey["path_elements"][5]
        print(name, interface, outDiscards, inDiscards, sep=',')
```

The JSON data looks like this and i am trying to access the AVG float for the key ["outDiscards]" (Scroll all the way to the bottom to find it):

```
{
 "notifications": [
  {
   "timestamp": "1590228300000000000",
   "path_elements": [
    "Devices",
    "ASDASDA23",
    "versioned-data",
    "interfaces",
    "data",
    "Ethernet6",
    "aggregate",
    "rates",
    "1m"
   ],
   "updates": {
    "alignmentErrors": {
     "key": "alignmentErrors",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 1
      }
     }
    },
    "fcsErrors": {
     "key": "fcsErrors",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 1
      }
     }
    },
    "frameTooLongs": {
     "key": "frameTooLongs",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 1
      }
     }
    },
    "frameTooShorts": {
     "key": "frameTooShorts",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 1
      }
     }
    },
    "inDiscards": {
     "key": "inDiscards",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 1
      }
     }
    },
    "inErrors": {
     "key": "inErrors",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 1
      }
     }
    },
    "outErrors": {
     "key": "outErrors",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 1
      }
     }
    },
    "symbolErrors": {
     "key": "symbolErrors",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 1
      }
     }
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "timestamp": "1590672660000000000",
   "path_elements": [
    "Devices",
    "ASDASDA23",
    "versioned-data",
    "interfaces",
    "data",
    "Ethernet6",
    "aggregate",
    "rates",
    "1m"
   ],
   "updates": {
    "inOctets": {
     "key": "inOctets",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 2252589.403482577
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 3062029.5123118195
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 1716651.1165519762
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 486507.3457503787
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 0.9999999999999999
      }
     }
    },
    "inUcastPkts": {
     "key": "inUcastPkts",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 4924.985636262933
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 6405.247375228221
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 4027.16222744576
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 856.3274693923914
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 0.9999999999999999
      }
     }
    },
    "outMulticastPkts": {
     "key": "outMulticastPkts",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 0.03331537922781352
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 0.09996021185548479
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 0.047115061840280935
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 0.9999999999999999
      }
     }
    },
    "outOctets": {
     "key": "outOctets",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 532952.2820988153
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 686277.7896707873
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 453320.58138715214
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 80364.91411229585
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 0.9999999999999999
      }
     }
    },
    "outUcastPkts": {
     "key": "outUcastPkts",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 4409.95750691497
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 5605.478585933741
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 3652.11719308749
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 677.6427171449172
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 0.9999999999999999
      }
     }
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "timestamp": "1590444480000000000",
   "path_elements": [
    "Devices",
    "ASDASDA23",
    "versioned-data",
    "interfaces",
    "data",
    "Ethernet6",
    "aggregate",
    "rates",
    "1m"
   ],
   "updates": {
    "outDiscards": {
     "key": "outDiscards",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 1
      }
     }
    }
   }
  },
```

I keep getting a KeyError, this is because if i print out just ["updates"] it only goes up to "SymbolErrors" in the JSON data, because it closes out with ))), i don't know how to access the second part of the data

Comment: `.get("inDiscards" or "outDiscards")` does not do what you think it does, it's just the same as `.get("inDiscards")`.

Comment: Ok, i have removed this and updated the above code

Comment: So, `notifications` contains an array of objects. Not every object contains the same keys in `updates`. So you need to conditionally access those, e.g. `if 'outDiscards' in JSONkey['updates']: ...`.

Comment: I have tested this and again, the key error produces itself

Comment: Well, yes… because you're naïvely accessing `JSONkey["updates"]["outDiscards"]` when this particular `JSONkey` doesn't have a `["updates"]["outDiscards"]` key…

Comment: This is where i am confused, because to me i can see the outDiscards Key at the bottom of the JSON data beneath "Updates":{

Comment: You understand that `"notifications": [ ... ]` is a *list of objects*? You understand that when you do `for JSONkey in notifications`, `JSONkey` will first be the first object in that list? You see that that first object does *not* contain that key you're interested in?

Comment: I understand the list of objects, however i thought that `for JSONkey in notifications` is the entire JSON data beneath "notifications", i do not know how to access the second object

Comment: Simply start with `print(JSONkey)`. You'll see that you're looping through several objects there.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance in breaking it down, i've done this and i am printing all 5 objects under "[updates"] but what i still cannot do is access the object containing "outDiscards"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Outdiscards was variably changing place, i fixed this issue with the try and except method and accessing the correct indexes

```
    inDiscards = JSONkey[0]["updates"]["inDiscards"]["value"]["avg"]["float"]
    name = JSONkey[1]["path_elements"][1]
    interface = JSONkey[1]["path_elements"][5]
    try:
        outDiscards = JSONkey[0]["updates"]["outDiscards"]["value"]["avg"]["float"]
        # print(inDiscards, outDiscards)
    except KeyError:
        outDiscards = JSONkey[2]["updates"]["outDiscards"]["value"]["avg"]["float"]
        # print(inDiscards, outDiscards)
```

Answer (score 0):

`inDiscards` and `outDiscards` is not in every `updates` you have and `.get("inDiscards" or "outDiscards")` doesn't do what you think it can.

Just check out `updates` dict you will find that both `inDiscards` and `outDiscards` are not in a single updates dict.

Comment: I have removed this, updated the above code but still get the same KeyError